# Performance, C++ Code and Assembly code generated

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

I have read many question about improving the performance of C++ and C code . Almost all the answer people have end up with observing assembly code generated by the compiler.

If I want to understand this technique, what are the best resource for that?

Comment: I highly doubt you are going to be able to do any better than a modern compiler with all optimizations enabled.

Comment: So you're asking for a book on assembly language?

Comment: The best way to assess and improve performance is to profile your code (in a profiler or by other means), then observe the worst offenders, improve the involved algorithm and optimize memory usage, and profile again.

Comment: Most compilers have a command line argument that triggers output of assembly language (e.g. `g++ -S`)... you can then study the resultant code.  It will typically be more readable than code generated by a disassembler, even if the object code had debug symbols embedded.

Comment: Improving performance on C/C++ code using assembly is usually not your best bet. *First* ensure you have fast algorithms in place, then optimize those in C/C++ code, and only when you can't get any further with C/C++ should you dive into assembly. In my practical experience C/C++ optimization yeilds a factor 2 - 10, while ASM optimization usually gets you no more than a factor 1.1 - 2.

Comment: My 20 cents: optimize architecture, algorithms, data structures -- in this precise order. Today's compilers are sophisticated enough to do this job better than you can. People who write those compilers are specializing in this kind of optimizations. From personal experience, sorry if it sounds like a drama: people who take the path of manual assembly optimizations (unless it's ABSOLUTELY necessary) sink in the small details and make little progress in the actual task at hand. Seen it more than once.

Comment: Personally I don't look at the assembly, but at the intermediate compiler representation. It's a bit higher level and allows to check for unrolling / loop-hoisting etc... What it does **not** cover is the memory-related bottlenecks; that is why **profilers** are best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Practice is your best teacher**

Write a simple test file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello %s !\n", "world");
}
```

then `gcc -S test.cpp` will give you the generated assembly code in `test.s`. Add `-Ox` if you want.

```
    .file   "test.cpp"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "world"
.LC1:
    .string "Hello %s !\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $.LC0, %esi
    movl    $.LC1, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 4.7.0-13) 4.7.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

If you have difficulties understanding the assembly language, you'd better start from `GNU assembly language` and [`linkers & loaders`](http://books.google.com/books/about/Linkers_and_Loaders.html?id=Id9cYsIdjIwC), and also [`Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual`](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html/). It is a great reference book.